# "They made life bitter for them" Shemot 1:14 - Question about the word וַיְמָרְר֨וּ

Tags: etymology, parashas-shemos

I understand there are valid points of view that the Torah isn't shy to speak in metaphor. There is also a side to say that every word in the Torah is true (see "Thinking Jewish Teenagers Guide to Life" by Rabbi Tatz, Ch. 13, a position held by Chassidus etc. - not here to debate that please)

*The following question only applies to the latter view, as obviously it doesn't exist in the former view. Please answer accordingly.*

What is the etymology of וַיְמָרְר֨וּ ? As far as I am aware, it literally means bitter taste, experienced in one's mouth. If so, how can it be taken out of that context to a poetic, metaphorical one of "bitter lives"?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question? Why can't it be understood as a verb "to embitter"?

Comment: @Dov because that is still a verb founded ultimately on a metaphor? Using the imagery of taste in the verb.

Comment: With respect I'm not sure if that is a correct assertion @Rabbi

Comment: @Dov I am making an assumption, that's why I am asking, perhaps my assumption is wrong. What is the etymology of the word, anyone?

Comment: It means bitter - and can be understood in verb and adjective form - https://www.pealim.com/dict/4309-mar/

Comment: are you asking if, literally, the Jews ate bitter foods so they could associate "bitter" with Egypt literally and only then can we extrapolate to a figurative understanding of "bitter"? I don't think that that is a necessary step -- the word "embitter" has a literal truth meaning that goes beyond its word-origin, as does "sweet" or "outstretched arm."

Comment: @rosends thanks, I think you are getting into my head. That makes sense. The concept of "bitter" is it's own thing, _not_ a taste in the mouth. It applies to taste in mouth because that is a _bitter_ (concept, not specific taste bud) taste.

Comment: @RabbiKaii the word might have developed from a word related to the mouth but words have more than one meaning even literally. It retains that mouth meaning but also refers to other things as being bitter not mouth based.

Comment: @rosends Ok I am happy for the question to be closed, or if you want, you can write this as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: *There is also a side to say that every word in the Torah is true.* Everyone says that, at least in normative Judaism. But I've never heard of an opinion that every word is literal.

Comment: @shmosel I am talking about the opinion, such as brought by Rabbi Tatz, e.g. here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/138830/31534

Comment: @rosends I believe the quotation I found and posted as an answer is very related or identical to what you said. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Tauber, in commentary on Chayav Inish:

> To illustrate by analogy, the term sweetness is applied in many
> different contexts. For example, food is described as being sweet, a
> melody is called sweet, a person is referred to as sweet, and there is
> even an expression, a *zisa savra*, a sweet idea. Now, within each of
> these categories themselves, there are many levels. There are many
> different types of sweet foods, songs, and persons. However, the
> difference between two types of sweet food is of a totally diverse
> nature than the difference between sweet food and a sweet song. The
> sweetness of both foods can be tasted by the palette, while the
> sweetness of a song requires the use of higher senses, and the
> sweetness of a person and an idea cannot be perceived by our physical
> senses at all. Nevertheless, the same term is used to describe all
> these four types of sweetness. **In other words, the same motif can
> exist on different planes and in different forms, and the lower
> manifestation of the motif can be seen as an analogy for the higher
> one** <sup>[based on *Bshaa Shehikdimu* 5672, Vol. II, p. 645; Vol III, p. 1220; *Kuntress  U'Maayon*, Discourse 21, ch. 1-2]</sup>

Chayav Inish et al clears this all up. This is ultimately founded on the concept of

> משל הקדמוני היא התורה, שהיא משל הקב"ה שהוא קדמונו של עולם
>
> The Primeval Analogy is the Torah, which is a mashal for The Holy One
> Blessed Be He, who is the Primary Being of the world (Rashi on Shemot 21:13, based on Makkot 10b)